# A value of type 'User?' can't be returned from the method '_userFromFirebaseUser' because it has a return type of 'User'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

[image: A value of type 'User?' can't be returned from the method '_userFromFirebaseUser' because it has a return type of 'User'.]

1. The argument type 'User Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User Function(User?)'.
2. A value of type 'User?' can't be returned from the method '_userFromFirebaseUser' because it has a return type of 'User'.

Answer (score 2):

Since you might return `null` from your function, you need to declare your function that `null` is possible, so instead of:

```
User _userFromFirebaseUser(auth.User user) {
  ...
}
```

You have to write it like this:

```
User? _userFromFirebaseUser(auth.User user) {
  ...
}
```

Mind the question mark - this essentially means, that this function will either return your `User` object or `null`, without the question mark, it always has to be an instance of `User`

Comment: great, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want `_userFromFirebaseUser` to return your `User` model, not `auth.User`, right?

```dart
User _userFromFirebaseUser(auth.User user) {
  return User(uid: user.uid);
}
```